# Can you refresh a browser programmatically using c#/wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've created a program that launches a wpf browser in c#. I've overloaded the exit button to hide the browser rather than close it on exit, and when the program is relaunched it's simply made visible (this why it doesn't have to reload every time).
However when it's made visible again, the page resumes the spot it was exited at, so on exit I'd like to hide and refresh the page (refreshing it will bring it back to its "home" page).

The code looks something like this as of now:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
       e.Cancel = true;
       //do my stuff before closing
      //dll import function to hide

}
```

If anyone knows a function I can use to refresh the page let me know. I'm using  [DllImport("User32.dll")] with FindWindow to hide the function.

Note that the page is launched through REST commands so closing it and reopening it is not an option.

Comment: You could probably send the `F5` key using the `SendMessage` API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SendKeys` to do this:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    //do my stuff before closing
    //dll import function to hide

    SendKeys.Send("{F5}"); //The page will refresh the browser.
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing this but VS doesn't seem to be picking up SendKeys as a key word.
  void DataWindow_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Cancel = true;
      SendKeys.Send("{F5}"); //This sends an error
    }

Comment: @JonahElbaz did you get this working? Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. It's not a windows Form, its a wpf chromium browser

Comment: Right, i understand that it's a WPF application, though, you can still add the reference. it will just pull in applicable libraries, which in your case, is where the SendKeys lives.